# MODX timeout limit

Tags: php, timeout, modx-revolution

I have a script which generates 3 different image sizes from a library of images and as you may guess, it takes a while to do its job-approximately 5 minutes for 400 images.
The default maximum execution time value of 30 seconds was not enough so I decided to change it in php.ini by setting
`max_execution_time = 1800;`, I checked the updated value in phpinfo() and it proved that the new time limit is 1800. Just to be sure that the error is not caused by mysl timeout either, I updated `mysql.connect_timeout = 1800`.

The problem is that my script is still timing out after 30 seconds when it should not be.

What I was thinking about setting

```
set_time_limit(1800)
```

at the beginning of every script involved in the process but this would require me to set it in processors, controllers and so on.
I was trying to search for some internal settings regarding script execution time but I have found none.

Does anybody have any ideas how to force script to run longer without timing out?

**UPDATE**

The error is 500

Answer (score 1):

MODX has nothing to do with it.  Change the setting in your PHP.ini: [Check the docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Also, why are you slamming such a heavy script all at once?

Use getCount to get a total number of them, then place a foreach loop processing a fixed number of images, inside another foreach loop which has a sleep or wait to taper out the load.

My server would probably process 400 images with little effort under 30 seconds.  You almost may want to look at memory_limit in your config.  I utilize 256 MBs, but I also have a couple dozen cores on the server with massive amount on memory.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion and therefore divided my script with foreach loops, which solves the problem of the default execution time limit. When it goes to my original question, the shared hosting did not accept changes applied to php.ini files and that is why my changes did not work...